# Why does the error for converting to pure virtual base class not appear at compilation phase?

Tags: c++

I have a contrived example. I think the key point is that there is an illegal conversion into a base class. I should not be able to have an array of MyBase.

This example compiles on my computer in VS2013:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct MyBase {
    virtual size_t Count() = 0;
};

struct MyContainer : MyBase {
    size_t Count() override;
};

size_t MyContainer::Count() {
    return 4;
}

int main() {
    MyContainer countable;
    MyBase x[] = { countable };
    std::cout << x[0].Count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this getting the same error on other compilers?

Why am I getting a linker error instead of a compiler warning?
(I do get an Intellisense warning)

### Note

The question is not what is happening here or how to fix it. I know that. I was wondering why it is a **linker error** instead of a **compiler error** and whether that is specific to my compiler only.

To make it clear, I know that this is a "fix":

```
int main() {
    MyContainer countable;
    MyBase * x[] = { &countable };
    std::cout << x[0]->Count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But fixing is not the issue here. What I do not understand is why the error is not diagnosed by the compiler but instead by the linker.

Comment: Your issue is `MyBase x[]` would have to either be an array of references or pointers for that to work.

Comment: No. I understand what is happening. My question is why that is not a compiler error but a linker error instead.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).  You might want to tag as [tag:visual-studio], too.  As far as I (and GCC) can see, the declaration of `x` is in error because `Count()` is pure virtual.  If I provide an implementation, then it does compile (because a `MyBase` can be constructed from a `MyContainer` by the compiler-defaulted copy constructor, i.e. object slicing) and the program correctly outputs `0`.

Comment: The reason it's a linker error is probably because your compiler isn't diagnosing the call to `virtual MyBase::Count()`, but is devirtualizing it.  Then your linker expects to find a definition for it.

Comment: FWIW, the `MyBase x[]` gives me compile errors in both GCC and Clang, both saying that the type of `x` is not valid because the class is abstract.  It's probably a bug in Microsoft's compiler.